# If a result already shows don't allow same keyup result to show

Tags: jquery

I'm dealing with Virtual Machines here. We host servers for clients to produce as many Virtual Machines as they'd like. If you're a System Admin I want to be able to search for any company in the database and have access to things like, how many VMs that company has, memory usage, firewall rules.

If I have a company from my database assigned to me(already gives me full access of that companies page without having to search for it) it's visible on my modal, I can click on it and it redirects me to that companies page. But, if I search for a company I already have access to, it duplicates the company name underneath the one already there. What I would like to do is hide the search result if that company name is already present so there are no duplicates. I was told I could do it in JQuery but I'm stumped.

```
$("#SearchValue").keyup(function () {
    if ($("#SearchValue").val().length === 0)
        return $('#ShowResult').html('');
    if ($("#SearchValue").val().length < 3)
        return;
    var searchCo = $('#SearchValue').val();
    var data = { "searchCo": searchCo };
    post(JSON.stringify(data))
        .to("SystemAdmin", "GetCompanyName")
        .done(function(results) {
            jQuery('#ShowResult').html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                $('#ShowResult').append('<a href="@Url.Action("SwitchCustomerTo", "Account")?customerId=' + results[i].CustomerID + '"> <i class="fa fa-home"> </i>' + results[i].CompanyName + '</a></h5></p>');
            }
        });
```

Comment: What are you talking about company assigned to you... Can you please try and clarify your question?

Comment: Alright. I edited original post. I think it better clarifies the problem. If not, then I'll just leave it as is and come back to it another day.

Comment: Thanks, much better.   Can you post the generated results code... What does the DOM look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can remove redundant entries from your anchor links. You would need to hold the customerID in an array and while iterating through each item in your result collection, check if that item already exists in the array or not.

```
$("#SearchValue").keyup(function () {
    if ($("#SearchValue").val().length === 0)
        return $('#ShowResult').html('');
    if ($("#SearchValue").val().length < 3)
        return;
    var searchCo = $('#SearchValue').val();
    var data = { "searchCo": searchCo };
    post(JSON.stringify(data))
        .to("SystemAdmin", "GetCompanyName")
        .done(function(results) {
           var itemArray = new Array();
            jQuery('#ShowResult').html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
            {
                if(itemArray.indexOf(results[i].CustomerID) == -1)
                {
                    itemArray.push(results[i].CustomerID);
                $('#ShowResult').append('<a href="@Url.Action("SwitchCustomerTo", "Account")?customerId=' + results[i].CustomerID + '"> <i class="fa fa-home"> </i>' + results[i].CompanyName + '</a></h5></p>');
               }
            }
        });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7j2wpde8/

Though I would advice you to remove the redundant entries on server side code. ( Assuming you are using C# as server side code, this is what you can do ).

```
[WebMethod]
public List<CustomerObject> GetCompanyName(string searchCo)
{
  List<CustomerObject> result = new List<CustomerObject>();
  var items = // get all company data from datasource
  result = items.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerID).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();
  return result;
}
```

EDIT :

Based on the updates on your requirement.

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<CustomerObject> GetCompanyName(string searchCo)
    {
      List<CustomerObject> result = new List<CustomerObject>();
      var items = // get all company data from datasource
      var itemWithCompanyAccess = // get the company for which you have access to data from datasource
      result = items.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerID).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();
      var duplicate = items.Any(x=> x.CustomerID == itemWithCompanyAccess. CustomerID).FirstOrDefault();
  if(duplicate != null)
result.remove(duplicate);      
      return result;
}
```